How to handle HTTP Content-Type header for cp932 and UTF-8-sig charsets
I'm trying to create a Python app (using the Pyramid framework) that should generate a CSV file.
Let's say code is looking like:
import io
from pyramid.response import Response


def generate_csv(request):
  data_example = 'あ,い,う,え,お\r\n1,2,3,4,5'
  encoding = request.GET.get('csv_encoding', 'cp932')
  data = data_example.encode(encoding=encoding)

  response = Response(
    content_type='text/csv',
    charset=encoding
  )
  response.body = data
  response.content_disposition = "attachment; filename=test.csv; filename*=utf8' 'test.csv;"
  return response

As you can see I'm getting CSV encoding from URL query parameter and it may be set more or less freely.
As result Content-Type headers value may be text/csv; charset=utf-8-sig or text/csv; charset=cp932 for example.
But here is list of "correct" charsets for Content-Type header, and I could find neither utf-8-sig nor cp932 here.
Should I handle charsets manually and add checks like:
if encoding.lower() in ('cp932', 'shift-jis', 'shift_jis'):
  header_charset = 'Shift_JIS'
elif encoding.lower().startswith('utf-8'):
  header_charset = 'UTF-8'

to sanitize charsets (e.g. cp932 → Shift_JIS) or there is no strict rule to use a charset from list above?
Currently I found that Firefox is adding BOM automatically to all CSV files downloaded with UTF-8 and UTF-8-sig charsets. But not sure what to expect for cp932 and other non-RFC charsets.
After I did some research about encodings in Python I found that

shift-jis has aliases: csshiftjis, shiftjis, sjis, s_jis
cp932 also has aliases: 932, ms932, mskanji, ms-kanji

In other side I found that aliases of shift-jis in charset list are MS_Kanji and csShiftJIS. looks like two encodings are merged in one, and here is no difference for browser between cp932 and shift-jis?
But what about utf-8-sig?
And what about solution in common, without digging into every encoding?

What it is CP932? it is ambiguous: IBM and MS used the same number. In general: avoid adding BOM on CSV: many tools cannot handle (and I think it is not officially recognized by Unicode for UFT-8, until September). RFC and web are strong on pure UTF-8. The BOM on UTF-8 should be used only on files which were default non-UTF-8 on microsoft, for just Microsoft use (else it is just an other complexification of Microsoft).

In general: avoid adding BOM → Firefox or some JS libraries that are used for download are adding BOM automatically (Chrome do not). I'm not familiar with frontend development, so not sure why it happens.  What it is CP932? → Saying honestly I didn't try to do research about difference between shift-jis and cp932 in deep. But I know that cp932 is enough for python to be able generate CSV with this encoding (even if it ambiguous) and cp932 is one of a standards for CSV documents, but cp932 is not a part of HTTP related RFC. So, how it should be handled?

I never saw such behaviour on Firefox, and for sure it will not do on non-Windows OS. i just tested with https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6666.txt and I do not see any BOM. (and all my CSVs, I never used cp932, many old mac and ibm and such obsolete encoding, so it may be a things on your field/region). Web is UTF-8 I'm surprised that any JS will add BOM which it is very non-standard. (w3c allows BOM, but without BOM and without other strong evidences, the files are considered UTF-8). Maybe are you using a strange extension?

PS: Just looking python: it interpret cp932 as the Microsoft variant: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. For instance, there is unclear (undefined) r in r.GET.get('csv_encoding', 'cp932')…

Isn't it somewhat problematic to let the client freely decide on the encoding, when you have fairly exotic characters (here: hiragana) which not all encodings are even able to encode?

@deceze It is just a reproducilble example. The question is even not about a python. The matter of question is: We have encodings in real world that doesn't exist in web standards. How to tell browser about these encodings and what browser behavior should be expected in this case?
